# Kohana PHP sessions problem under a local network

Tags: php, session, proxy, kohana, authentication

I have a kohana (php) web site and we have a problem with the sessions when used by computers on a local network under a proxy.

The problem:
PC 1 and PC 2 are in the same local network. They use a proxy server to access the external web site.
PC 1 access the site with "USER A", he is in the main page now and the site says "Connected with USER A".
PC 2 enters the site and access with "USER B", he is in the main page now and the site says "Connected with USER B".
PC 1 press F5 to reload the site main page, and the site now says that is logged with "USER B".

The system is installed externally and we have this problem only in this under-proxy network. Access from other PCs also under local networks (but no proxy) don have this problem.

We enabled the "user_token" part in the auth module (it uses a new table named "user_tokens" that uses the browser user agent), but the problem persists.

-- edit --
We are using Kohana 3.0, PHP 5.2.9 and postgres 8.4

Comment: What Kohana version are you using?

Comment: Does that happens in that network with other Kohana (or PHP) sites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your proxy support caching? It should **NOT** cache pages which are different if the client is logged in.

You application may have to set appropriate HTTP headers to tell the proxy that it is not allowed to cache HTTP responses.

If this doesn't fix it, make sure you're not using the client IP address as the Session key.
(If you still fancy using the IP, create a whitelist for allowed proxies, then use the HTTP forwarded_for header. It'll only fix the problem for proxies you trust though.)

Comment: I solved it. It was a headers problem, so i supose that the proxy was caching it.

Comment: I added this: header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
                header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
                header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
                header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
                header("Pragma: no-cache");

Answer (score 0):

Can you turn the proxy off temporarily to confirm the issue?

Can you try accessing the site with Firefox and the Firebug extension? This will let you see the exact HTTP response codes and headers that are being sent from the site. Knowing what they are will help us diagnose the problem for you.

Comment: we can't turn off the proxy, but we are trying to change it (use another one).

Comment: We can't turn off the proxy, but we are trying to change it (use another one). I don't think is possible to install firefox and firebug... since users that local network are not techicals enough i cant instruct them to analize that. Anyway it helps me to do some tests with the headers.